# Internal microphone not working in laptop MS-6837D with Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, drivers, sound, skype, microphone

I cant use the microphone in my ubuntu 12.10.
I don't know at all what it the reason. 
My sound settings input tab displays some device, but I am not sure if that is my microphone. 
I use the skype test call to test if the mic is working but I never hear my voice.
Why I can't use my microphone? what is missing?

[image]

**Update**
I tried also to use

```
pavucontrol
```

This is how my settings there look like:
[image]
[image]

The second image looks like the mic is taking input, but it is not. That bar is there just shaking and is always the same lenght. 
I don't know what it could be.
I just noticed that in this link https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LaptopTestingTeam/MSI%20X320?highlight=%28%5CbCategoryLaptop%5Cb%29 
it says that in msi laptops the mic does'nt work. 
Is there any way to fix it?

Here is my part of my hardware configuration:

```
Computer
Processor   2x AMD Athlon(tm) X2 Dual-Core QL-60
Memory  3791MB (913MB used)
Operating System    Ubuntu 12.10
User Name   username (username)
Date/Time   Sat 12 Jan 2013 00:35:23 GMT
Display
Resolution  1366x768 pixels
OpenGL Renderer Unknown
X11 Vendor  The X.Org Foundation
Multimedia
Audio Adapter   HDA-Intel - HDA NVidia
Input Devices
Lid Switch  
Sleep Button    
Power Button    
Power Button    
AT Translated Set 2 keyboard    
ENE eHome Infrared Remote Receiver  
MCE IR Keyboard/Mouse (ene_ir)  
Video Bus   
Video Bus   
SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad  
HDA NVidia Line 
HDA NVidia Mic  
HDA NVidia Headphone    
HDA NVidia Line Out 
Printers
No printers found   
SCSI Disks
ATA WDC WD3200BEVT-2    
TSSTcorp CDDVDW TS-L633A    
Operating System
Version
Kernel  Linux 3.5.0-21-generic (x86_64)
Compiled    #32-Ubuntu SMP Tue Dec 11 18:51:59 UTC 2012
C Library   Unknown
Default C Compiler  GNU C Compiler version 4.7.2 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.2-2ubuntu1)
Distribution    Ubuntu 12.10

Board
Name    MS-1671
Vendor  MSI
```

Comment: Does the input level shown on that window react to mic input?

Comment: Are you using Acer Aspire One 722? If so please go to https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/1074615 and indicate you are affected by this bug.

Comment: We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.

Comment: @iSeth I am using an MSI laptop, sorry didn't answer before I didn't see the comment.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install [Pulseaudio Volume Control (`pavucontrol`)](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/banshee) [image: Install banshee] and check if your input port and profile selections for your sound card are correct. Such settings appears to be missing in the regular Sound Settings in Ubuntu.

General troubleshooting from here:

1. Open `pavucontrol`.
2. Click the *Configuration* tab.
3. Locate the correct sound card (just one in your case, probably).
4. Select the appropriate profile. For regular analogue sound, you should select something like *Analogue Stereo Duplex*. Options depend on the capabilities of your sound card.

   Screenshot (KDE, but looks similar in Unity):

   [image]
5. Click the *Input Devices* tab.
6. Locate the correct sound card again.
7. Check the setting of the *Port* selection for it. My laptop offers me three options: *Internal mic*, *Microphone* (jack) and *Line In*.
8. Check if it's *unmuted*.

   [image]